# Eclipse - how to debug input parameter change

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have the following problem, we might even call it a classic one:

```
public void myMethod(Map<Object, Object> parameter){

    someOtherObject.method(parameter);
    .
    .
    .
    someOtherThirdPartyObject.method(parameter);

}
```

And suddenly, in the end some method touched the input parameter Map, and I don't know where and how. Now, I know it would be desirable to make the parameter immutable, but it is not and that is the root of the problem. For instance, the methods inside myMethod are intended to perform some validations, but they do some more as well, which is wrong by design.

So, the question is how to create a breakpoint in this method where the execution pauses if an attribute of this parameter Map changes? It might be a good idea to put a conditional breakpoint after each method call, but if you have 20-odd methods, it's rather painful.

How can I debug when this input parameter is changing?

Answer (score 2):

What you want appears to be called a "watchpoint". I actually didn't know this functionality existed and I used to work on the Eclipse Project!

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_add_watch.htm

It looks like you'll have to figure out what fields are being editted and then set a "Write" watchpoint using the help document above.

Additionally, Eclipse highlights variables which are modified, so if you step over your method calls one by one you will be able to see which one is modifying the value (and which field is being modified) because it will be highlighted (bright yellow, by default) in the "variables" tab in the "debug" perspective. Once you know which method if modifying the data you can run debug again, but this time debug the method that changes the value and just keep repeating until you find the problem.

Comment: I said watch panel, but watchpoint is  the correct term. And I forgot that you can actually mark it so it highlights when there are changes. +1

Comment: I never used this before, so I'm going to give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic problem solving scenario where you start with a very large search space and systematically and methodologically narrow it down until the search space is small enough for you to locate the problem.

If you're trying to locate a spot where your map is being modified incorrectly, you might want to first start at the higher levels of the myMethod. Put breakpoints around the methods called inside the myMethod method. At each breakpoint, look at the contents of the Map. Eclipse has a variable watch panel where you can see the contents of every variable at a specific moment in time.

When you hit the breakpoint where you notice something is wrong. Stop. You now know to dig into `someOtherObject.method(parameter);` assuming the data was changed at it's breakpoint.

Now, someotherObject.method will likely have other methods inside it. Put your breakpoints inside this method around all of it's function calls and repeat the process.  Continue repeating until there are no more methods left. Eventually, you will narrow down the problem and have the answer.

Unfortunately, there is no magic "fix my code" button for these types of problems. It just takes good, old fashioned Sherlock Holmes style investigative skills and reasoning to eliminate areas of the code that you know aren't the problem until you're left with a smaller section that allows you to get at the root cause.

Comment: Yes, you might be right and currently I do as you described but it just takes to much time if you have a large map and you cannot really see with your eyes the change in the upper right corner whereas programmatically it does not seem to be too complicated for an IDE to tell me if a value was altered or added.

Comment: Depends on the situation, but in your case it sounds like a watchpoint is the answer :)

Comment: No, it's not :( I tried also the method breakpoint but I don't know how to "save" the initial state of the input parameters, so I cannot even watch the size of a Collection as I don't have anything to compare it to. I know the old fashioned style works, it's just not very convenient, maybe I'm spoiled a bit.

Comment: I feel more comfortable with the old route. If the debugger starts solving it's own problems, we could be out of jobs ;)  Think of it this way, at least the "old fashioned" way, you'll definitely understand why your problem occurred, how to fix it, and how to attack similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If no code modification is allowed, you can

- use the watchpoints method described by acattle to watch changes at this specific map instance or
- have breakpoints in the Map methods modifying its state (if you want to do that for multiple instances). It does not matter that the Map code is binary only, you can still open it using Ctrl-Shift-T (Open Type), select the methods like put(...) or remove(...) in the outline view and add breakpoints using the context menu in the outline view.